# BASH print lowest numbered strings in a variable

Tags: bash

i'am currently writing a skript to remove old folders. Something like a log rotation.
the directory contains folders like: (where 12345678 is epoch time from the creation)
123-1.2.3.4-12345678

i now did manage to get the skript sort out all the not used folders and older then X days.
I now want to remove all folders with the lowest numbers in the filename except of the the X newest.

the foldernames are saved in a variable like:

```
123-1.2.3.4-12345679
123-1.2.3.4-12345680
123-1.2.3.4-12345681
123-1.2.3.4-12345682
```

how can i find out which are the X newest and save the other ones in a vairable to remove them in a next step.

Comment: What does the code look like? Instead of doing this by folder name, use the age of the folders. Basically find command of folders not modified for X days  and delete them. If you need to limit how many are deleted just build that into the logic ..

Comment: Is the variable an array?

Comment: yes, the variable is an array. in theory i could use find, but i need to exclude the ones with a smylink (in use). I've already done that and saved the ones in a variable

Comment: please update the question to show a) the contents of the array (`typeset -p arrayname`), b) the expected results (corresponding to the data in the array) and c) the code you've tried so far

Comment: will all foldernames have the same prefix (`123-1.2.3.4-` in the sample provided) or could the prefix differ? if the prefix could differ ... does the removal operation need to be performed *solely* on the epoch value or does the prefix also need to be taken into consideration (eg, keep the latest folder for *each* unique prefix)?

Comment: Is the list already sorted? Assign it to an array and take the two on the appropriate end.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the directory names do not include newline characters,
would you please try:

```
#!/bin/bash

# example of an array of directory names
dirnames=(
    "123-1.2.3.4-12345679"
    "123-1.2.3.4-12345680"
    "123-1.2.3.a.b-12345681"
    "h5p-32.ad-12345682"
    "foo bar baz-12345678"
)
x=2                                     # remove older directories except for the x newest ones

for d in "${dirnames[@]}"; do           # loop over the directory names
    ts=${d##*-}                         # extract the timestamp
    printf "%s\t%s\n" "$ts" "$d"        # prepend the timestamp to the directory name delimited by a tab character
done | sort -nrk1,1 | tail -n +$(( x + 1 )) | cut -f2- | tr "\n" "\0" | xargs -0 echo rm -rf
```

- `sort -nrk1,1` sorts the directory names with the timestamp in descending
  order (newest first, oldest last).
- `tail -n +$(( x + 1 ))` outputs `x+1`th line and onward.
- `cut -f2-` removes the prepended timestamp.
- `tr "\n" "\0"` converts a newline character to a null character to preserve
  blank characters in the directory names combined with `xargs -0`.

If the output looks good, drop `echo` prior to `rm`.

If you instead want to save the output in an array, change the last four lines to:

```
mapfile -t array < <(for d in "${dirnames[@]}"; do
    ts=${d##*-}
    printf "%s\t%s\n" "$ts" "$d"
done | sort -nrk1,1 | tail -n +$(( x + 1 )) | cut -f2-)
```

Then the array `array` will hold the directory names to be removed.